# partial rejection?

Tags: phd, peer-review, paper-submission

I submitted a manuscript and the review was kind of mixed.
There are two reviewers, one said accept with minor revision, the other one did not say "reject this" but it seemed that he required major revision.
According to two editors they will accept my paper but it will be subject to how I revise.
So I revised the original manuscript and made a letter containing point by point answers, of course.

I inquired the status of the manuscript and just got an email saying that the revision was sent out for another round of review.
Is is normal? because the editors said they would accept mine but it would be subject to revision,  I thought the editors will be deciding whether they are going to accept or not without any further review.

Comment: It's normal. The reviewers need to check that you answered their points satisfactorily. If not, they will ask you to make more changes.

Comment: got it. Probably I misunderstood something. Thanks!